# Access Table - Changing Existing Field to Lookup

Tags: ms-access

I'm working on Access Microsoft 365. I have a table with 3000 entries, one of the fields is called "Artist" (includes the name of the artist). I've decided to turn this into a Lookup field, and make a table of the Artist names (so that they are all spelled correctly and the user can't misspell a name). Since the data is there already, how can I ask Access to use the data that's there and compare it to the Artist table (hoping that it's a match)? Everything I've tried deletes the Artist Name from all 3000 entries.

Comment: Edit question to show combobox properties, including the RowSource.

Answer (score 0):

I advise not to build lookups in table. Just build combobox on form.

Do a Find Unmatched query to identify records in your data that do not have a match in Artists table. Access has a query wizard for that. Manually correct spelling for any bad records located.

You can save the artist name into your data but a better alternative may be to replace the name field in your data table with a number field for storing ArtistID. This will involve an UPDATE action SQL using a JOIN of the two tables on the name fields. Once the new foreign key field is populated, delete the unnecessary name field from your data table.